# Value of scrollHeight is undefined?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and wanted to implement **Infinite Scroll**, but my values of `scrollHeight` is undefined.I'm using `ElementRef` from `@angular/core`.Here's my code.

```
@Input() eachElementHeightInPx = 20;
@Input() fetchThreshold = 5;
private element: HTMLElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

@HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
onScrollContainer($event: any) {
    console.log('scrollContainer');
    console.log('scrollHeight ' + this.element.scrollHeight); // it is undefined idk why!!.
    console.log(typeof (this.element[0]));
    if (this.element.scrollHeight > this.lastCheckedHeight) {
        this.previousScrollHeight = this.element.scrollHeight;
        let remainingHeight = this.element.scrollHeight -
            (this.element.offsetHeight + this.element.scrollTop);
        let remainingElement = Math.ceil(remainingHeight /
            this.eachElementHeightInPx);
        if (remainingElement < this.fetchThreshold) {
            this.lastCheckedHeight = this.element.scrollHeight;
            // this.fetchMore.emit();
            console.log('emitting');
        }
    } else if (this.element.scrollHeight < this.previousScrollHeight) { // To check if the list is reloaded
        this.previousScrollHeight = this.element.scrollHeight;
        this.lastCheckedHeight = 0;
        this.element.scrollTop = 0; // Scroll the list to top
    }
}
```

Here's my function snapshot just in case the above code is not lill confusing.
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbO1x.png).
Please explaing ways that **do not include jQuery**.Thanks.

**UPDATE:VERY MINIMAL STACKBLITZ REPRODUCTION**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qngk3b

Comment: Just a sidenote : if you want an infinite scroll, [use the CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview), it will be easier. If you want to train, then good luck !

Comment: Just to make sure: Is it just the `scrollHeight` property which isn't defined or is it `this.element`?

Comment: yeah well said @trichetriche , Angular CDK is very good option for such use case, if it suits your requirements

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] of your issue on https://stackblitz.com ? It would be easier for us to identify the issue

Comment: @trichetriche stackblitz link is there now. Please Check.

Comment: "A class member cannot have the 'const' keyword." means you need to put this code inside a method.